# How to allow for some space between introduced Programming Code and text

Tags: spacing

I'm using the following ( the latex code is not from my authorship, I just used one from a question I asked here a long time ago.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{language=Mathematica}
\lstset{basicstyle={\sffamily\footnotesize},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  numbersep=5pt,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos={t},
  frame={lines},
  rulecolor=\color{black},
  framerule=0.5pt,
  columns=flexible,
  tabsize=2,
  mathescape,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}

Insert Random Code

\end{lstlisting}


How do I increase the space between this text and the code above. If I use slashes it gives me an error...

\end{document}
```

Comment: `aboveskip=5ex,belowskip=5ex`

Comment: @Manuel Where do I put that?

Comment: Following the other keys, of course `\lstset{..,aboveskip=5ex,belowskip=5ex}`. The `5ex` dimension was an example, you can change it to whatever value you find correct.

Comment: Is this for this listing only or should this affect all listings?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina For all, but feel free to show how to do it for just a specific one. ;)

Comment: For just one: `\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=5ex,belowskip=5ex]...\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina You should answer the question. The only thing I did was opening the documentation of `listings` hit Search, and search for “above” and *voilà*, the first result was the answer.

Comment: @Manuel I think *you* should answer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`listings` has the keys `aboveskip` and `belowskip`. Just put some value and that's all. You can pass it globally with

```
\lstset{aboveskip=5ex,belowskip=5ex}
```

or localy with

```
\begin{lstlisting}[aboveskip=5ex,belowskip=5ex]
  ..
```